# Excel Groupby and Sum Returning Error due to blank rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, group-by, countif

I have a dataset with the following structure

```
email               category
jjabrms@abc.com     action
tim.owns@abc.com    horror
jim.camrn@abc.com   romance
jjabrms@abc.com     sci-fi
jim.camrn@abc.com   action
trent.li@abc.com    action
trent.li@abc.com
tim.owns@abc.com    
sunil.bhat@abc.com  sci-fi
jj.abrms@abc.com    horror       
jj.abrms@abc.com
```

and am trying to produce a column 'sum_category' that would group by email to get the sum of unique category values for each unique email like this

```
email               category     sum_category
jjabrms@abc.com     action       3
tim.owns@abc.com    horror       1
jim.camrn@abc.com   romance      2
jjabrms@abc.com     sci-fi       3
jim.camrn@abc.com   action       2
trent.li@abc.com    action       1
trent.li@abc.com                 1
tim.owns@abc.com                 1
sunil.bhat@abc.com  sci-fi       1
jj.abrms@abc.com    horror       3
jj.abrms@abc.com                 3
```

Assuming Column A is 'Email' and Column C is 'category', I have tried using the following code but it is producing #DIV/0! error

```
SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$100=A2)/COUNTIFS(C$2:C$100,C$2:C$100,A$2:A$100,A$2:A$100))
```

I have also tried using the following code but it is counting the blank values into the sum

```
SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$100=A2)/COUNTIFS(C$2:C$100,C$2:C$100&"",A$2:A$100,A$2:A$100))
```

Appreciate any help I could get to resolve this, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you don't have Office 365, else this would be straightforward, for example using the following spill formula:

```
=LET(
    α, A2:A12,
    β, C2:C12,
    BYROW(α, LAMBDA(ζ, COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(β, (α = ζ) * (β <> ""))))))
)
```

Otherwise, don't use the reciprocal `COUNTIF`/`SUMPRODUCT` set-up: it's incredibly slow compared to the following `FREQUENCY`/`MATCH` construction, in `D2`:

```
=SUM(
    IF(FREQUENCY(
        IF(A$2:A$12 = A2,
            IF(C$2:C$12 <> "", MATCH(C$2:C$12, C$2:C$12, 0))
            ),
            ROW(A$2:A$12) - MIN(ROW(A$2:A$12)) + 1
        ), 
      1
    )
)
```

and then copied down to `D12`.

Comment: the SUM IF options works beautifully. Thank you!